# Not to Queue Jobs at Spring Quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I have followed that tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

My configuration file is as follows:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="runMeTask" class="com.mkyong.common.RunMeTask" />

<!-- Spring Quartz -->

<bean id="runMeJob" 
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="targetObject" ref="runMeTask" /> 
    <property name="targetMethod" value="printMe" /> 
</bean> 

<!-- Cron Trigger, run every 5 seconds -->
<bean id="cronTrigger" 
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My printMe function is called at every 5 seconds. However if some delays happens at that function I see that next jobs are queued. However I don't want it. How can I do it at Spring?

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to run concurrently (e.g. you may have two jobs running at once) then either don't implement `StatefulJob` (Quartz < 2.0) or don't use the `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` annotation (Quartz >= 2.0).

If you want the second one to not run at all then I don't think Quartz has anything built in.  You could use a TriggerListener as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366483/how-to-skip-a-particular-job-execution-in-spring-quartz-scheduler).  Or just modify your job so the first thing it does is check if the previous job finished and return immediately if it hasn't.